# Cannot find VLC web plugin while compiling VLC 2.0 from source

Tags: vlc

I compiled VLC 2.0.0 on Ubuntu 11.10 successfully, however I couldn't find the VLC Web Plugin for playback of video from HTML.

In referring to http://www.videolan.org/doc/vlc-user-guide/en/ch07.html

I configured, compiled and installed VLC with the following commands:

```
./configure --enable-mozilla
make
su
Password:  [Root Password]
make install
```

I downloaded the VLC source code from here http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-sources.html.

So, the question is, where is VLC web plugin in VLC 2.0?

Comment: Where is the question? ;-)

Comment: The question is I couldn't find VLC web plugin for Mozilla or chrome browser. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been split off from vlc & you'll have to build separately. Atm not sure where you'll get tarballs other than from debian or launchpad, Example - 
https://launchpad.net/npapi-vlc

For the latest git, After downloading cd to source & run `./autogen.sh`

```
git clone git://git.videolan.org/npapi-vlc.git
```

git shortlog page has snapshots if you don't want the latest, info on commits, ect 
http://git.videolan.org/?p=npapi-vlc.git

Comment: Thanks doug. I have no idea where is this hiding until you shown me the repo. Compiled and run successfully. Cheers!